# How to purge and competely reinstall tryton

Tags: software-center

I made a mistake when trying to install Tryton. I think I deleted an important part of a text file when trying to configure it.This is the error message I get: [image] I didn't realize that the username was admin, that was where the trouble started. It just won't open up at all any more. I have tried these commands

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:rayanayar/tryton-3.6
sudo apt-get purge tryton-modules-account
sudo apt-get purge sudo apt-get purge tryton-modules-account-product
```

The problem may be that I do not know how to purge neso. This is because in the software center it says Neso and there is not a command line name there.

I wish to purge and completely reinstall Tryton. How do you do this without doing a complete reinstall of the system? Again, thank you for all of your help, I really appreciate it.

Comment: How did you install it in the first place?

Comment: `sudo apt-get autoremove --purge tryton-client`

Comment: @ARG-sudo add-apt-repository ppa:rayanayar/tryton-3.6.

Comment: @Alex, your comment worked, if you put it down as an answer I will vote for it.

Comment: @BJsgoodlife I put it down in the answers section.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`sudo apt-get autoremove --purge tryton-client`

Comment: That only gives one part of the answer.

Comment: You might also take a look at `ppa-purge`